# Cannot access table without public.table name. Is there a way to get rid of public?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `user` in PostgreSQL which cannot be accessed until I specify the fully qualified name `public.user`.
`SHOW search_path` gives me:

> $user,public

Is something wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

`USER` is a reserved word in both [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and standard SQL. Do not use as a table name.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess, it works if you use:

```
SELECT * FROM "user";
```

But if you try:
    SELECT * FROM user;
it returns your current username?